# Is the Quotient Space Spanned by the Image of the Basis?

Tags: tensor-products, quotient-spaces

*This is related to the definition of the tensor product space $V\otimes W$ as a qoutient space $C(V\times W)/N$, where N is some nice space*

Let $C(S)$ be the $\mathbb{K}$-free vector space on an *arbitrary* set $S$, the latter constitutes a basis in the former. Let $H$ be a subspace whithin $C(S)$. Then the canonical projection
$$
\pi:C(S) \rightarrow C(S)/H
$$
is a surjective linear map, provided the set $C(S)/H$ has vector space structure, i.e., there is an addition and multiplication with scalars defined on it. (assumed to be known to you.)

**Question**: Is the space $C(S)/H$ spanned by the image of $S$ through $\pi$ ? i.e., is the following true
$$
{\rm span}\{\pi(x)\ |\ x \in S \} = C(S)/H
$$

My Answer: $$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \pi(x_i) = \pi\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i\right)   \hspace{1 cm} {\rm where} \hspace{1 cm} x_i \in S, a_i \in \mathbb{K}, n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
Read forwards implies: ${\rm span}\{\pi(x)\ |\ x \in S \} \subseteq \ C(S)/H$. Read backwards implies: ${\rm span}\{\pi(x)\ |\ x \in S \} \supseteq \ C(S)/H$.

I'd like to know what is wrong about it and if this true for *any* vector space $V$, with a basis {$e_i$}, and a subspace $H \subseteq V$

Comment: The claim you are making is indeed correct and is valid in a very vast general setting. Without reaching the highest degree of generality at which this claim could be made, let me point out that for given arbitrary ring $A$, left $A$-modules $M$ and $N$ and *surjective* morphism (of $A$-modules) $f  \colon M \to N$, if $S \subseteq M$ is a *generating system* for $M$ then $f[S]$ is a generating system for $N$.

Comment: Just as a remark on method, the description you give above is not the correct *a priori* definition for tensor products. In principle, the tensor product between a *right* module and a *left* module (the factors occurring in this order!) over one and the same ring bears no more than an abelian group structure. When that common ring happens to be commutative, the tensor product can naturally be equipped with a module structure over the same ring.

Comment: Sorry for reducing the generality, since I'm a physics student, but the claim is still correct even for infinte dimensional vector spaces, right ?

Comment: No need to apologise! My remarks were not meant as reproaches but as snippets of information for you. Yes, the remark is valid for structures as general as groups with operators (of which modules are particular cases and vector spaces even more particularly so).